# print selected text using xpath in selenium pyhton

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

#Code

```
Alert_threshold_values = services.get_texts_by_xpath("/html/body/div[4]/app-root/app-home/div/div/div/app-inventory/div/div/app-sensors/div/div/app-sensors-info/div/app-sensor-info-summary/div/div/div[3]/app-sensor-chart/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]")
```

Output

> ['Jun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMJun 7 03:27 PMDate0.04.00.51.01.52.02.53.03.5Illuminance\nLight_Sensor_639Critical Alert Thresholds: NoneMajor Alert Thresholds: 4000Minor Alert Thresholds: None']

I just need to print from Light_Sensor to Minor Alert Threshold.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the substring of your result. As you're using this in Python, the simplest solution is probably to take the substring in Python. With XPath functions, I think
`substring($res, string-length(substring-before($res, "Light_Sensor")))`
might do the trick, where $res is the XPath string in your question.

Comment: I didn't get your point here. how can i resolve it.

Comment: You can add the following lines after your code. I'd suggest you read an introductory Python book to become more familiar with the language.

`Alert_threshold_values = Alert_threshold_values[0]; Alert_threshold_values = Alert_threshold_values[Alert_threshold_values.index('Light_Sensor'):]`